# missing argument 2 when passing arguments to add_action

Tags: actions, parameter

I wanted to pass arguments to a function triggered by an add_action hook. I followed the [codex on this](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/do_action).
I got a warning and the result was erratic, with an unexpected behavior.

This question has already been adressed [before](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/using-arguments-with-add_action-and-do_action) without answers.

I could reproduce this problem with a simplified function echoing the 2 arguments it needs. So, in `functions.php`:

```
function my_function ($arg1, $arg2) {
    echo 'id1: '.$id1.' id2: '.$id2;
    return;
}
add_action('this_hook', 'my_function', 10, 2);
```

The 2 number stands for the number of arguments needed by `my_function` in order it can take into account some of its context when executed.

So, to be executed, the `do_action` must be added in the template pages files, for example in `header.php` as it was the case for me.

```
 do_action('this_hook', 'dogs', 'cats');
```

The result is echoing

> id1: id2:
>   id1: dogs id2: cats
>   Missing argument 2 for my_function()

The expected behavior would have been:

> id1: dogs id2: cats

Comment: You realize that your function name is `add_custom_submenu` but you are using `add_bp_custom_submenu` as the callback, right?

Comment: Thanks for having taken a look to my question. I verify very carefully (it is driving me crazy :) : but the code is ok with the same function name, it's only when writing the question i made the mistake. I apologize and edit the question to correct it. Please take into account the problem is not from the function name. Here is a gist if needed : https://gist.github.com/Nandrine/9d2083c5978c5c229ae0

Comment: @s_ha_dum I don't understand why this question has been marked as off-topic. I now have the answer and I'd like to share it if I can? The problem I met can be reproduced when hooking in whatever hook that has already been triggered by a do_action in the core files. In that particular case, demanding arguments when registering a new function within an add_action('hook','function', $priority, $nb_arguments) will have as consequence to issue this warning, as well as another side effects. I can explain how to avoid this too if it interests somebody.

Comment: Rewrite/edit so that the question is more general (not so plugin specific) and it can be reopened.

Comment: I've rewritten the question. Just to explain, when i was confronted to the problem, `this_hook` was a hook of buddypress which name is `bp_setup_nav` used to build the main menu. Thanks to the explanations I received here, I was able to find that this hook was already used elsewhere. But the problem is not specific to the buddypress plugin, but to the hooks mechanism.

Answer (score 2):

This problem can be met when hooking in whatever hook that has already been triggered by a precedent `do_action` (ie. when `this_hook` has already been mentionned in a `do_action` within the core files of wordpress or within whatever plugin files)

In that particular case, demanding arguments when registering a new function within an `add_action('this_hook','function', $priority, $nb_arguments)` could have as possible consequence to issue this warning, as well as another side effects, like the repetition mentionned.

To explain, let's say `this_hook` has been triggered twice like this:

- in a core or plugin file: `do_action( 'this_hook' );`
- by the developer in a template page file: `do_action( 'this_hook', 'dogs', 'cats');`

So, if you meet erratic behavior when passing arguments to `add_action`, you should verify if it is used in another place in the code (with a different number of arguments). Then, of course, as you don't want to modify the core o plugin files to add the two arguments saying there are missing, one solution is to trigger the "registering" of the `add_action` on another localized hook in the template.

Let's imagine that there are other hooks localized in the file header.php, lets say something like `do_action( 'before_header')` and another one `do_action('after_header')`

Then in `functions.php`:

```
function trigger_function () {
    add_action( 'this_hook', 'my_function', 10, 2);
}
add_action( 'before_header', 'trigger_function');

function remove_function () {
    remove_action( 'this_hook', 'my_function');
}
add_action( 'after_header', 'remove_function');
```

In `header.php`, you should have something like this:

```
do_action('before_header');
....
do_action('this_hook', 'dogs', 'cats');
....
do_action('after_header');
```

Comment: +1, but I would argue that you should not be firing _action_ hooks except in the places they are fired in the Core or in the application providing the hook. It seems like a very good way to get unexpected behavior. The same is probably true of some filters.

Comment: Indeed. Do you mean that we should never add `do_action` on an existing hook in the template files? In my case, I wanted to modify the menu by calling this hook, which is OK until I began to think it would be great that this can be done dynamically, by passing arguments taking account some context variables. The prefered solution (not to access global variables) usually mentionned is to add a `do_action` in a template file with the arguments. I followed this way without being aware the consequences! Passing arguments to a function  through `add_action` seems to be very tricky.

Comment: This helped point me in the direction.  I added `10,99` to my two hooks so they execute later.  thank you.

Answer (score 0):

From your [Gist](https://gist.github.com/Nandrine/9d2083c5978c5c229ae0) you register your hook like so:

```
add_action( 'bp_setup_nav', 'add_bp_custom_submenu', 10, 2 );
```

...but you try to fire it by the function name:

```
do_action( 'add_bp_custom_submenu', 213, 'dashboard' );
```

...when you should be firing by the *hook* name:

```
do_action( 'bp_setup_nav', 213, 'dashboard' );
```

Comment: Yes, i dit it like this first, with the hook_action_name 'bp_setup_nav', with the same result. I changed it (and it remains in the gist - corrected since thanks) to test as I can't understand how WP could know wich function to trigger, when there are several ones pluggued into the same hook.

Comment: I can tell something else, like the other person mentionning the problem here http://wordpress.org/support/topic/using-arguments-with-add_action-and-do_action?replies=6, the bp_nav_menu I'm trying to modify is repeated twice (without being modified by the function of course).

Comment: I updated the gist with more details. I tried to investigate why bp_nav_menu has been excuted twice. I print the bp_nav_menu content before and after the do_action. You'll see how it is duplicated, and it seems that the function 'add_bp_custom_submenu' HAS been executed ONCE despite of the warning. Please visit the gist : https://gist.github.com/Nandrine/9d2083c5978c5c229ae0

Comment: I think there's some misunderstanding as to how you're implementing hooks. I would go back to basics and simply make the two functions echo a unique string. Fire the hook, check your output. Now things should be making sense.

Comment: OK, I'm sure i'm doing all wrong! I simplify as you suggested (one function with two parameters, same hook in add_action and do_action in header.php) and put it in another gist. https://gist.github.com/Nandrine/31e261579559c82de5eb Results are the same, executed twice, one with the warning, one OK

Comment: I understand calling do_action in the template is too late, because the 'bp_setup_nav' is executing before. That's certainly the reason why my_function() is executed twice, once without being initialized and another time with the do_action. It's certainly not the behavior i want. I just want to be able to have a parametrised function plugged in 'bp_setup-nav' in order to manage customized menus. How can i pass arguments to add_action ?

Comment: Your new gist has completely stumped me - I've no idea why you're getting a missing argument error. Is this a vanilla (clean) install of WordPress, without plugins?

Comment: No, I'm sorry, it's not vanilla install because I thought I had not understand how to parametrize an add_action. Despite reading a lot, I don't really understand the basics concepts of do_action to pass the args for add_action hook: why the arguments can not be passed directly in add_action('hook', 'function', $priority, $argument1, $argument2) which has the advantage to link the arguments with the right function. As i was wondering, how WP recognize which function to give the parameters in case several functions are hooked in the same hook ? I'm missing smthg. I'll try it on a fresh install

Comment: I understand your frustration, but the issues you raised are in fact the very things that make hooks great. The whole idea is that a hook represents an event (and sometimes the event has data - arguments), and anyone (i.e. a plugin or theme author) can listen out for it and do something too. Trying to pass arguments to the *registering* of a hook (i.e. `add_action`) hints at a fundamental misunderstanding of them, and I would suggest you need to rethink your approach.

Comment: please see last gist https://gist.github.com/Nandrine/31e261579559c82de5eb I understood what's going on, thanks to your explanation, and rethinking my approach ;)